# Article défini "les", mais défini par qui? et comment?

Tags: articles, partitif, articles-definis

Si je dis :

> les hommes sont bêtes.

l'article « les » est supposé *défini*, mais qui en donne la définition ?

Est-ce que ça n'inclut **que** les hommes bêtes (peu importe le nombre, mais du coup c'est indéfini ou en tout cas indénombrable, du coup c'est plutôt un article partitif non ?) Si c'est le cas, « les » peut inclure un seul homme si on imagine un univers où seul un homme est bête.

Ou

est-ce que ça qualifie **tous** les hommes comme étant bêtes en tant qu’affirmation ? Et dans ce cas, la phrase

> Tous les hommes sont bêtes.

est un pléonasme qui ne devrait jamais être utilisé non ?

Comment: Défini a deux sens.

Comment: Without addressing your particular example, I'm tempted to take issue with your closing remark about never using pleonasms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source : *réponse d'une rédactrice travaillant pour l'Académie Française, au Service du Dictionnaire.*

> Monsieur,
>
> En tant que rédactrice au Service du Dictionnaire et comme mes
>   collègues, je réponds aux nombreuses questions de langue adressées à
>   l’Académie française. Il ne s’agit en aucun cas d’une déclaration
>   officielle de l’Académie française, qui nécessiterait que les
>   académiciens statuent en séance sur le sujet. Je précise par ailleurs,
>   qu’aucune réponse apportée dans le cadre du courrier ne peut être
>   invoquée comme preuve dans le cadre d’un conflit juridique.
>
> Cependant, cette réponse se veut la plus exacte linguistiquement
>   parlant. Je répète donc que lorsqu’on dit Les hommes sont bêtes, on
>   énonce grâce à l’article défini et au présent dit de vérité générale,
>   une loi générale, qui n’exclut pas cependant que certains hommes
>   échappent à cette loi ; alors que lorsqu’on dit Tous les hommes sont
>   bêtes, aucune exception n’est envisagée.
>
> Veuillez agréer, Monsieur, mes meilleures salutations.
>
> S. Tonolo
>
> Service du Dictionnaire

Comment: réponse de http://www.academie-francaise.fr/

Comment: J'ajouterais l'idée suivantes: Les énoncés dans les langues dites naturelles se disent ***sur une toile de fond comparative***. Donc, des phrases comme "Tous les X sont Y" se disent à l'exclusion d'autres phrases possibles: certains hommes, aucun homme, plusieurs hommes et ainsi de suite. Sans "tous les", on est dans l'assertion logique, qui certes, peut aussi faire partie de la langue naturelle mais aussi d'une langue logique.

Answer (score 4):

Je vois ça comme deux façons de dire la même chose. La deuxième est une assertion plus générale, donc plus forte.

On peux faire le rapprochement avec la différence entre ces deux phrases :

> Il n'y a pas de survivants
>
> Il n'y a aucun survivant

L'information est la même (le nombre de survivants est 0) mais la deuxième formulation est plus "forte".

La phrase "*Les hommes sont bêtes.*" est une généralité assez vague, cela laisse entendre qu'il peut y avoir des exceptions.

En revanche, "*Tous les hommes sont bêtes.*" implique qu'il n'y a pas d'exception. On peut d'ailleurs encore accentuer en disant "*tous, sans exception*"

Comment: "tous, sans exception" est clairement un pléonasme qui n'apporte aucune information. Pour ce qui est de ta définition qui préconise que "les" est donc pas inclusif, tu tires ta source d'où? c'est juste ton avis subjectif ou bien c'est le consensus de l’académie française? (c'est ça qui m’intéresse personnellement, n'y voit aucune attaque à ton avis personnel ^^), d'ailleurs c'est aussi mon interprétation mais précisément j'aimerais Objectiver l'information.

Comment: @Matrix D'abord, je rejoins Papa Poule sur le fait qu'un pléonasme n'est pas forcément inutile ou une erreur. Il peut avoir une valeur stylistique, ou servir à accentuer (voire "suraccentuer") comme ici. Ensuite, même s'ils ne sont pas forcément collés, on peut pas vraiment dire "sans exception" sans "tous". "*Ils sont tous morts, sans exception*" : un peu redondant, mais "*Ils sont morts, sans exception*" ça marche juste pas, il manque quelque chose ^^

Comment: @Matrix Concernant la deuxième partie de ton commentaire, c'est bien mon avis personnel basé sur ma jugeote après réflexion, ça vaut ce que ça vaut ! Personnellement, je pense que c'est plutôt ça, ensuite je compte sur le vote des autres pour savoir s'ils pensent la même chose ou pas :)

Comment: je suis logicien, 0 ça veux dire 0, on ne peut pas dire mieux que 0 si la vérité est 0, donc tous pléonasmes est une perte de temps et d'énergie quand deux entités communiques des informations de manière rationnelle :) Mais j'entends bien pour l’aspect "stylistique"  :)

Comment: "Tous, sans exceptions" est effectivement un pléonasme qui lève cependant toute ambiguïté. Il n'est en effet pas rare de lire ou entendre "Tous les hommes sont bêtes...sauf le mien". Le "sans exception" renforce l'idée du "tous" qui pris seul est parfois utilisé à mauvais escient/par abus de langage pour signifier "l'immense majorité"

Comment: @Matrix Un énoncé dans un langage humain a en général une portée plus grande qu'une assertion en logique (voir [les fonctions du langage selon Jakobson](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Jakobson#Les_fonctions_du_langage_selon_Jakobson)), d'un point de vue informationnel, « tous », en ajoutant de l'emphase peut par exemple servir à communiquer que l'importance de l'énoncé pour le locuteur.

Comment: c'est une mauvaise façon de procéder, si quelque chose est important pour toi, tu dois le dire et pas essayer d'éventuellement avoir le possibilité de mettre l'accent indirectement dans l'espoir qu'il puisse peut être comprendre qu'en fait c'était important pour toi ^^ Faut arrêter de compliquer la communication en la rendant cryptique, tu dis ce que tu as a dire point. #RelationHommeFemme